# How to reference stored database images in template of Django?

Tags: python, django

I made a form in Django that enable users to write something in text boxes and upload images. The uploaded images will go to `/media/` directory. Everything is fine save one thing. I can't display those images in my template. 
I tried following ways but it didn't work.
this is views.py's snippet:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(default='default.png', blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and this is my template, that I want to display respective images a user uploaded.

```
<div class="articles">
    <div class="article">
        <h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
        <img src="/media/{{ object.thumbnail }}/" alt="">  # didn't work
        <p>{{ object.body }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Kindly help me solve this, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by accessing url attribute in your `thumbnail` field of `Article` model.

For an instance,

```
<div class="articles">
    <div class="article">
        <h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
        <img src="{{ object.thumbnail.url }}/" alt="">  # This would get url of thumbnail
        <p>{{ object.body }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```